# Should I use MessageDigest to verify a digital signature that signed in C#?

Tags: java, c#, rsa, digital-signature

I'm new in Java and want to sign some data in c# and verify in Java with RSA and SHA512.

C#:

```
static string SignData(string message, RSAParameters privateKey)
    {
        byte[] signedBytes;
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] originalData = encoder.GetBytes(message);
                rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
               
                signedBytes = rsa.SignData(originalData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
    }
```

Java:

```
 static boolean verifySignature512(String message, String sign, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] contentDigest = digest.digest(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha512withRSA");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
    signature.update(contentDigest);
    return signature.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(sign));
}
```

I used RSA and public and private keys. Java function always return false with no error or exception.
If I remove MessageDigest like below it starts working, Is it ok and secure?

```
static boolean verifySignature512(String message, String sign, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
   // MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
   // byte[] contentDigest = digest.digest(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha512withRSA");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
    signature.update(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return signature.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(sign));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature verification on Java-side has to fail as you are using different hashing algorithms on both sides.
In C# you are using SHA1 ('HashAlgorithmName.SHA1') and the Java-part is using SHA512 ('Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha512withRSA");').

The following code is using SHA1 as hash algorithm but you can easily change this (on all codelines :-) to SHA256 or SHA512.
The C#-code verifies the signature with the public key, the same public key (encoded as PEM) is used in the Java-code
for verification only.

**Security warning: My example codes are using UNSECURE 512-bit RSA-keys that should not used in production.
There is not proper exception handling and you are using the padding 'RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1' which should
NOT used anymore as well.**

This is the output of my C#-code:

```
Should I use MessageDigest to verify a digital signature that signed in C#?
signedData: mU2bcCMEhG13xG9sKwhaA//dnw2+rbLkwz2737cNU5kb2EBenJIEJ+bA596XccCVKUKPanxMUFoVw2fl8HhCNw==
The data was verified.
```

That's the Java-output:

```
RSA instance: SHA1withRSA
The data was verified.
```

C#-code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class RSACSPSample {
    static void Main() {

        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Should I use MessageDigest to verify a digital signature that signed in C#?");
            // Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
            ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

            string message = "this is the important message to sign";

            // get private and public key ### SAMPLE and UNSECURE 512 bit RSA keypair
            var privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>mfgthqgvK5P6kP00ojzA68+tGMwjEacduojFSukazKPXrZ8Q5XjzfqgJmDQ3wcWe3hWK92O3z/tmAuN47KA0ZQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>8VCRao0hZmIv5gVGFLqOD/7n6TQKlekA96U1QVzimKM=</P><Q>o1bchWA5ddDd59FED37QcrakoTXNoxRspFtsLDKEp1c=</Q><DP>ugF0VUE7wYNlkFP4VPoHjuTZNbRbhHn5uOmrRxqlvyk=</DP><DQ>XoGggC9Hr8pUyo9DIPAP7X+Ny5TU0Vm87m/TK9Ni+2s=</DQ><InverseQ>YqOHEP8dgCvz5Q8nhpQgdrKfdlmjkNAFxKF7j3pm09I=</InverseQ><D>mCpGy/rxS08e5iXn26LRQvvm5UfyLKMNZWmAGk2QF8cRGFB7dds/SI9wGTC9xyOoF4N2kWzYdLx+dYbR9lqwbQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>";
            var publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>mfgthqgvK5P6kP00ojzA68+tGMwjEacduojFSukazKPXrZ8Q5XjzfqgJmDQ3wcWe3hWK92O3z/tmAuN47KA0ZQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
            
            // Create a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
            RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            RSAalg.FromXmlString(privateKey);
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = RSAalg.ExportParameters(true);

            String signedData = SignData(message, rsaParameters);
            Console.WriteLine("signedData: " + signedData);

            // verify with xml-public key
            RSAalg.FromXmlString(publicKey);
            rsaParameters = RSAalg.ExportParameters(false);
            bool verifiedData = VerifyData(message, signedData, rsaParameters);
            
            // Verify the data and display the result to the
            // console.
            if (VerifyData(message, signedData, rsaParameters)) {
                Console.WriteLine("The data was verified.");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("The data does not match the signature.");
            }
        }
        catch(ArgumentNullException) {
            Console.WriteLine("The data was not signed or verified");
        }
    }
    
    static string SignData(string message, RSAParameters privateKey)
    {
        byte[] signedBytes;
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] originalData = encoder.GetBytes(message);
                rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
                signedBytes = rsa.SignData(originalData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
    }
    
    public static bool VerifyData(string message, string signedData, RSAParameters rsaParameters) 
    {
        byte[] messageBytes;
        byte[] signedBytes;
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        try
        {
            var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            messageBytes = encoder.GetBytes(message);
            signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signedData);
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
            return rsa.VerifyData(messageBytes, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signedBytes);
        }
        catch(CryptographicException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Java-code:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MainSha1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        System.out.println("Should I use MessageDigest to verify a digital signature that signed in C#?");
        String message = "this is the important message to sign";
        // this is a SAMPLE and UNSECURE RSA 512 bit key
        String publicKeyPem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJn4LYaoLyuT+pD9NKI8wOvPrRjMIxGn\n" +
                "HbqIxUrpGsyj162fEOV4836oCZg0N8HFnt4Vivdjt8/7ZgLjeOygNGUCAwEAAQ==\n" +
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String signedData = "HS4qvrXpqu97me7yDt9lWXp+QLjKMO8FY4kiUiGhMhi6KmXQXCtmcUWSbg0i+LXv7u5ueRiQNeBnu6UCbPhZLg==";
        String rsaInstanceString = "SHA1withRSA";
        System.out.println("RSA instance: " + rsaInstanceString);
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromString(publicKeyPem);
        boolean verifyData = verifyRsa(publicKey, rsaInstanceString, message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedData));
        if (verifyData = true) {
            System.out.println("The data was verified.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The data could NOT get verified.");
        }

    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String publicKeyPEM = key;
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "");
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = (PublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
        return pubKey;
    }

    public static Boolean verifyRsa(PublicKey publicKey, String rsaInstanceString, byte[] messageByte,
                                    byte[] signatureByte) throws SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance(rsaInstanceString);
        publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        publicSignature.update(messageByte);
        return publicSignature.verify(signatureByte);
    }
}
```